# Mongodb cursor is returning null

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in my database called example that looks like this:

```
{
    "event" : "cheat",
    "message" : {
        "tableid" : 398,
        "time" : 1381853438870,
        "link" : "/dbcheat/table398/iID485"
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("525d68fe99ddc6a019000008")
}
```

There are thousands of records like this and I would like to look for the first 50 for instance.

I researched that the best way to go through this would be to use the forEach() function. I am used to SQL and just started with Mongo and understand that objectID is unique but I cant get an order from it.

```
var cursor = db.example.find();
cursor.forEach(function(x){

    console.log(x.message);

});
```

But I am getting an error because for some reason because x is always null.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, do you want to get all records or the first 50?

Comment: are you running this function on mongo shell ?

Comment: @LucianEnache Well the end goal is to get the first x number of records but for now I want to print them all out. But when I do this x is always null.

Comment: @ShreyanceJain no I am using node js

Comment: @vcazan and which module you are using to connect mongodb ?

Comment: @ShreyanceJain mongojs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add a handler in the find() for function( error, cursor ) and within that cursor, assuming error is null and cursor exists, then you do cursor.toArray( function( error, data ) )

In the first one, you have to wait for the data to come and expect an error.
In the second one, the cursor will be turned into an usable array of jsons :> which is what you needed.

```
db.example.find( function( error, cursor)
{
    if( error || !cursor)
    {
        console.log("error getting items");
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.toArray( function( error, items)
        {
            if( error || !items)
            {
                console.log("error getting items");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log( JSON.stringify( items ) );
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay I changed my function to this which seemed to have worked but the last row is an error. How would I handle this
    db.example.find().forEach(function(error,x){

Comment: This code has a syntax error and I cant figure out why. Missing a } on the second last line

Answer (score 0):

To look at the "first 50" you might want to sort the documents by time and limit the query result to the first 50 initially.

```
db.coll.find().sort({"message.time":1}).limit(50)
```

You could then use the toArray() method on the cursor and access the documents within that array.

Comment: I am trying to read the value of the arry after I save it but I keep getting undefined? var last50 = db.example.find().sort({"message.time":-1}).limit(50).toArray();

console.log(last50[0]);

Comment: Can't see the reason, the query works fine for me. Can you try it in the mongo shell first, without the toArray() and check if you see any results at all?

Answer (score 0):

To print the first X number you could just use a pattern like :

```
db.example.find().limit(x);
```

Where x is an integer specifying the first `x` elements of the collection

If you want to get them all just use

```
db.example.find()
```

While if you want to skip the first `y` elements and print the next `x` use something like

```
db.example.skip(y).limit(x);
```

Also to have some sorting you could use the time field for that.